# Detect lines with UPPERCASE words and style them with BOLD lines using PHP+CSS

Tags: php, css, regex, html

Not sure if this can be achieved. In a database field ("$features") there is information with this pattern:

```
SUBHEADING:
- feature1
- feature2
- feature3
SUBHEADING:
- feature1
- feature2
- feature3
- feature4
SUBHEADING:
- feature1
- feature2
... etc.
```

I needed to print it on screen using an unordered list:

```
<ul>
  <li>SUBHEADING:</li>
  <li>- feature 1</li>
  <li>- feature 2</li>
  <li>- feature 3</li>
  <li>SUBHEADING:</li>
  <li>- feature 1</li>
  <li>- feature 2</li>
  <li>- feature 3</li>
</ul>
```

So using PHP, I did:

```
<ul><li><?=str_replace("\n","</li><li>",$features);echo"</li>";?></ul>
```

Until there, no problem. Now I need to apply **BOLD** to all the **SUBHEADINGS**. I think the pattern would be, applying `<strong>` after `<li>` and `</strong>` before `</li>` where cursor finds a line where all letters, or words better, are `UPPERCASE`. That could be a way, not 100% sure.

Probably there are more efficient ways, the issue is that I don't know how to place what I just wrote in terms of code. May be using regular expressions, not sure. I appreciate any help, idea or advice.

** **UPDATE / SOLUTION** **

```
<?php
    echo "<ul>";
    $features = explode("\n", $features);
    foreach($features as $v) {
       echo "<li>";
       $v = str_replace(':','',$v);
       echo ($v === strtoupper($v)) ? "<strong>".$v."</strong>" : $v;
       echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Are there always going to be 3 feature elements? If *yes*, then you could do `li:nth-child( 4n+1 ) { font-weight:bold;   }` if you want a purely `CSS` solution - http://jsfiddle.net/z8Pm9/

Comment: No, the number of features is irregular.

Comment: and what is when the "title" is not on each 4th element? A pure css solution wont work

Comment: Is there any special reason for the -1? it seems this is becoming a trend on stackoverflow, you can't ask anything because 'some people' assume that you should know everything about the subject before asking it.

Comment: dont know, but i think the -1 people gave a -1 because he cant answer on the question. Yep thats a trend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ctype_upper](http://www.php.net/manual/function.ctype-upper.php) function. If you have all the string in a variable, you can try this:

```
<?php
    echo "<ul>";
    $features = explode("\n", $features);
    foreach($features as $v) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo ctype_upper($v) ? '<strong>'. $v .'</strong>' : $v ;
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot Chris, I think this is a more clean solution to also add `<li></li>` to every line of the string, however the `ctype_upper` function isn't returning `true` in the `exploded` lines containing the SUBHEADINGS, probably because of the `colons ":"` at the end of the SUBHEADINGS. But I think I'm very close, thanks again!

Comment: If I change `ctype_upper` for `strtoupper` it adds `strong` to every line \" damn.

Comment: Solved using an `str_replace` and validating using `strtoupper` instead `ctype_upper`. Check update on question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strtoupper` to check that:

```
if(strtoupper($string) === $string) {
    // make it bold
} else {
    // normal text
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I did this:

    <? if(strtoupper($features) === $features) {$features = "<strong>".$features."</strong>";
     echo $features;
     } else {
     echo  $features;
     }?>
But it didn't work, I think it never going to be true because not all strings in $features are uppercase.

Comment: Than you cant! Your questions have only defined that subheadings are uppercased!

Comment: @JohnA10 because `$features` is the whole data set, not individual headings. You need to split each heading into a substring and process that array in this manner so you are only testing for `SUBHEADING:`